# Custom user store manager class not showing in user store drop down

Tags: jdbc, wso2, osgi, osgi-bundle, wso2-identity-server

i am writing a custom user store manager by extending JDBCUserStoreManager and place my jar to WSO2 dropins directory my user store is successfully initialize but custom user store is not available on user store drop down menu
i am following this link
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Writing+a+Custom+User+Store+Manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation you have pointed only explains how to use the custom userstore manager as the primary userstore.

You need to register the userstore manager as a osgi service like done for [JDBCUserStoreManager](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/blob/v4.4.3/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/internal/UserStoreMgtDSComponent.java#L75-L76)

Comment: Thanks for replying i have already register my Userstore and log is also showing that my CustomuserStoremanager is activated successfully and my userstore do authenticate method is also running but i dont know why this customuserstore is not showing in userstore drop down

Comment: Thanks my custom user store is listed now

Comment: Hello @AnkitPawar how your store is displaying now. I am also facing the same issue. could you please tell me how you fixed it ?

Comment: create user store as osgi bundle and put the jar in dropins folder create storemanager like this https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/blob/v4.4.3/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/internal/UserStoreMgtDSComponent.java#L75-L76