# Custom user store manager class not showing

Tags: java, jdbc, wso2, osgi, wso2-identity-server

I am new to doing wso2 development. We are running version 5.3 and I am trying to experiment with writing a custom secondary user store. Our primary one is an LDAP server and we would like to configure our system to also use a, database backed, a secondary custom user store. 
to get this project off the ground I have been following the instructions on 
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Writing+a+Custom+User+Store+Manager. When placing the jar in the dropins directory my custom store manager does not appearing on the list of user stores.

After a bit more digging, I found this article [Custom user store manager class not showing in user store drop down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48863240/custom-user-store-manager-class-not-showing-in-user-store-drop-down). This appeared to address my exact issue. However after adding the CustomUserStoreManagerServiceComponent class, I am still unable to get the plugin to appear in the drop down.

The source for this project is here https://github.com/terellda/src-questions. I know the project is incomplete but I am trying to get this first issue addressed so that I can continue.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Custom User Store manager. Use this as a Sample.

https://github.com/Manukam/wso2-custom-user-store